# Chrome running as root and using 100% cpu

Tags: google-chrome

My computer would freeze and become totally unresponsive for around 30 secs. Looking at the system monitor, I saw the chrome process running as root and taking up 100% CPU. Any idea what's happening?

[image: Screenshot of system monitor process property]

Comment: Well did you start chrome with a preceding sudo?

Comment: Nope. I think its pretty difficult to start chrome as root. I installed my chrome from the official Google site. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175967/how-to-run-google-chrome-as-root-in-linux

Comment: The users finds a way… ;) Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948536/chrome-running-as-root-and-using-100-cpu?noredirect=1#) your question and give us the output of `top` when the problem occurs, in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: Did you [search AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=chrome+cpu) for answers? There seem to be many questions addressing similar issues. See also the *Related* column on the right side.

Comment: While "chrome cpu" is a very common question, "chrome root cpu"  doesn't return any results. My main concern is that I might be infected with malware. Will report back with more info when the problem reoccurs.